# Encrypt Android Setting

Tags: android, encryption, paypal

For my Android application, I want to release it for free, but with ads. Then, I want to give the user an option to remove the ads for a nominal fee using the PayPal library. That way, I don't have to have 2 separate versions of my application that I have to monitor, develop, etc.

Anyways, after the user pays me to remove the ads, I need to securely store something that indicates that they paid so that it isn't easy to spoof my app. How should I do this? I was thinking of encrypting a string and storing that encrypted value in SharedPreferences. Is that a viable option? If one were to take the apk off of their device and give it to someone else, does SharedPreferences move with it, or is it saved outside of the apk? What about if someone has root access? Can they spoof SharedPreferences?

If possible, I'd like to avoid having to query a server every time the app is launched.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue a few of points:

1. Refactor your application into a free, ad supported version and a paid version.  You can package things such that you'll be able to share almost every piece of the application.  Then just post the free and paid versions in the market.
2. Anyone willing to work their way around your copy protections was never going to pay for your app anyway.
3. You're offering a value proposition.  If the only thing that separates your free and paid version is ads then your app better be something the user can't live without.  If you're planning on expanding the paid version with more features then #1 above is probably a better idea anyway.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is take some unique data from the phone (device ID, app version...etc...) in your app and combine that into a message.

Then use a public/private key pair. The public part can be in your app and the private part you keep with you.

When a user pay for your app, it sends you the string with device ID and so on and when you got the payment, you send back a blob of data containing a certificate.

Your app can verify the certificate against the device ID or whatever your decided to put in there by using the public key.

There are still a lot of details you'd have to work out (how the data is sent back and forth...etc...), but with those kind of tools, you should be able to achieve what you are looking for.

You can look here about how to manage certificates : http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/cert/package-summary.html

Of course, how sophisticated you want to be depends on your app and how much people will have to pay for. Reverse engineering to bypass all that is certainly possible, but I doubt many people would go through the trouble if they only have to pay $0.99 to get rid of the ads.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is determined enough, they will be able to reverse-engineer your app and get the decryption key, or just patch away your protection altogether. SharedPreferences are stored in a file that is accessible to anyone (ok, maybe anyone will root access...).

In summary, save yourself the effort and don't even try to protect your app... who is going to reverse engineer your app to merely get rid of advertisements anyway?

Comment: You beat me to it.  "Give up" is my advice.  If you're asking for help here then whatever system you devise will be cracked within minutes.  If you check online they'll remove the check. If you encrypt something in your code they'll decrypt it.  And so on.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to skimp on the complicated protections for now and wait until in-app purchase arrives. I'd imagine there would be a secure, reliable solution at that point in time.